# Hash tables using latex

Tags: tables

Looking to create a hash table with linked lists in LaTeX like the one below:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It would be very helpful if you could create an MWE. This will dramatically increase the possibility that somebody is willing to help you.

Comment: It will also increase the chances that somebody understands what you want well enough to help you. Right now, I have no idea what you are trying to do. I know you want to make a table with `#` symbols and link something in the table to some list or lists. But that is rather vague.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Tikz to draw a Hash Table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64430/using-tikz-to-draw-a-hash-table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also with `tikz` using nodes and the `positioning` library. This solution can be particularly useful in case of more complex connections.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (0);
\foreach \t[count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as\j using int(\i+1)] in {
 110  ,
 100  ,
  90  ,
  80  ,
  70  ,
  93  $\rightarrow$ 60 ,
  50  ,
  40  ,
  96  $\rightarrow$ 30 ,
  97  $\rightarrow$ 20 ,
  120 $\rightarrow$ 10
}
\node at(\i.south)[anchor=north,draw,minimum height=2em,minimum width=1.5em,outer sep=0pt](\j){}
    node at(\j.west)[align=right,left]{\i} 
    node at(\j.east)[align=left,right,xshift=-.7em]{$\rightarrow$ \t};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** - as per the OP's comment:

You can also make room for numbers to be inserted in the table cells like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (0);
\foreach \t/\n[count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as\j using int(\i+1)] in {
 110/  ,
 100/1  ,
  90/12  ,
  80/  ,
  70/122  ,
  93  $\rightarrow$ 60/111 ,
  50/56  ,
  40/  ,
  96  $\rightarrow$ 30/ ,
  97  $\rightarrow$ 20/ ,
  120 $\rightarrow$ 10/34
}
\node at(\i.south)[anchor=north,draw,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2.5em,outer sep=0pt](\j){\n}
    node at(\j.west)[align=right,left]{\i} 
    node at(\j.east)[align=left,right,xshift=-.7em]{$\rightarrow$ \t};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: ,@Katie Li - Please see my edit as per your comment below Werner's solution.

Comment: This is perfect, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `tabular`-like representation of a hashtable, wrapped inside a similarly-named environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{hashtable}[1][]
  {\begin{tabular}[#1]{
     @{} 
     > {\small} r <{\normalsize~\rlap{\fbox{\strut~~}}$~~\rightarrow$~}
     @{} l @{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}

\begin{hashtable}
   0 & 110 \\
   1 & 100 \\
   2 &  90 \\
   3 &  80 \\
   4 &  70 \\
   5 &  93 $\rightarrow$ 60 \\
   6 &  50 \\
   7 &  40 \\
   8 &  96 $\rightarrow$ 30 \\
   9 &  97 $\rightarrow$ 20 \\
  10 & 120 $\rightarrow$ 10
\end{hashtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really helpful - thanks so much

Comment: How would I edit the environment header to increase the width of the table? (i would like to add numbers inside but most of them extend past the size of the table)

Comment: Inside the table? Where inside? I've made it such that the boxes are always empty using an `\fbox`.

Comment: @KatieLi: Could you show a picture of what you mean?

Comment: http://imgur.com/X8ye3vF

Comment: @KatieLi: Perhaps consider [this definition](http://pastebin.com/7HM70HBG).